# ArrayList<String> method

Tags: java, arraylist

I was given this code

```
public ArrayList<String> inputForMethod_7() {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();


    return a;
```

So far I’ve created my array list, but I need to add strings so that if this method is run as an argument on the following:

```
public String method_7(ArrayList<String> list) {
    if (list == null || list.size() < 3) { return null; }
    String s = "";
    for (int i=1; i<list.size(); i=i+2) {
        s = s + list.get(i).charAt(i);  
    }
    return s;
```

This must return “yes”.

Comment: @Vucko I need to add strings into the array list in my “inputForMethod_7” so that the method_7 returns “yes"

Comment: explain your question. be specific on what are you saying. be on track , say it step by step. dont just narrate the story.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I understand the problem, the solution should be as follows (I haven't tested it, so it might need some more tweaks):

```
public ArrayList<String> inputForMethod_7() {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s0 = "whatever"; // i starts at 1, so we will skip the 0th element of the List cause i=1
    String s1 = "xyx"; // we only need the 'y' at position 1, x can be whatever
    String s2 = "whatever"; // we skip this one because i=i+2
    String s3 = "xxxex"; // i=3, that's why we need the 'e' to be in position 3
    String s4 = "whatever"; // we skip this one because i=i+2
    String s5 = "xxxxxsx"; // i=5, that's why we need the 's' to be in position 5

    a.add(s0);
    a.add(s1);
    a.add(s2);
    a.add(s3);
    a.add(s4);
    a.add(s5); 

    return a;
```

And now just call your `method_7` like this:

```
String result = method_7(inputForMethod_7());
```

And do with the result whatever you need to.

> Note that also the string indexes start at 0, that's why I'm putting the character we need ('y', 'e' and 's') into the positions they're in.